How is the World to Come preceded by suffering?
The Talmud says:

Rabbi Shim'on ben Yoḥai says: The Holy One, Blessed be He, gave Israel three precious gifts, all of which were given only by means of suffering: Torah, the Land of Israel, and the World to Come... [Berakhot 5a]

Torah was preceded by the pain of slavery and the Land of Israel by the pain of war.  But what suffering precedes the World to Come?  A painful death?  What if the death is not painful?  Judgment?  What if the judgment is favorable?  The Talmud continues:

The World-to-Come, [because,] as it is written: “For the mitzvah is a lamp, the Torah is light, and the reproofs of instruction are the way of life”. [Proverbs 6:23].

I don't understand.  How is the World to Come preceded by suffering?

suffering of withstanding from sin?

I would prefer to say: All the suffering that comes in a normal life.  But that's too general.

It seems from here that the less you enjoy this world, the more you enjoy the world to come: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Berakhot.61b.4.2?lang=he&with=all

The Gra explains that gemara to mean avodas hamusar. To work on yourself and breaking your middos is the suffering the gemara is refferrimg to.
(Gra qouted in fancy even shleima, propably somewhere on mishlei)

The first answer to the OP's question comes from mishna Pirkei Avos 4:22

הוּא הָיָה אוֹמֵר, הַיִּלּוֹדִים לָמוּת, וְהַמֵּתִים לְהֵחָיוֹת, וְהַחַיִּים לִדּוֹן. לֵידַע לְהוֹדִיעַ וּלְהִוָּדַע שֶׁהוּא אֵל, הוּא הַיּוֹצֵר, הוּא הַבּוֹרֵא, הוּא הַמֵּבִין, הוּא הַדַּיָּן, הוּא עֵד, הוּא בַעַל דִּין, וְהוּא עָתִיד לָדוּן. בָּרוּךְ הוּא, שֶׁאֵין לְפָנָיו לֹא עַוְלָה, וְלֹא שִׁכְחָה, וְלֹא מַשּׂוֹא פָנִים, וְלֹא מִקַּח שֹׁחַד, שֶׁהַכֹּל שֶׁלּוֹ. וְדַע שֶׁהַכֹּל לְפִי הַחֶשְׁבּוֹן. וְאַל יַבְטִיחֲךָ יִצְרְךָ שֶׁהַשְּׁאוֹל בֵּית מָנוֹס לְךָ, שֶׁעַל כָּרְחֲךָ אַתָּה נוֹצָר, וְעַל כָּרְחֲךָ אַתָּה נוֹלָד, וְעַל כָּרְחֲךָ אַתָּה חַי, וְעַל כָּרְחֲךָ אַתָּה מֵת, וְעַל כָּרְחֲךָ אַתָּה עָתִיד לִתֵּן דִּין וְחֶשְׁבּוֹן לִפְנֵי מֶלֶךְ מַלְכֵי הַמְּלָכִים הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא:
He (R'Elazar haKapar) used to say: the ones who were born are to die, and the ones who have died are to be brought to life, and the ones brought to life are to be judged; So that one may know, make known and have the knowledge that He is God, He is the designer, He is the creator, He is the discerner, He is the judge, He the witness, He the complainant, and that He will summon to judgment. Blessed be He, before Whom there is no iniquity, nor forgetting, nor respect of persons, nor taking of bribes, for all is His. And know that all is according to the reckoning. And let not your impulse assure thee that the grave is a place of refuge for you; for against your will were you formed, against your will were you born, against your will you live, against your will you will die, and against your will you will give an account and reckoning before the King of the kings of kings, the Holy One, blessed be He.

Rashi explains the bold part:

שעל כרחך אתה נוצר. שבא לו מלאך הממונה על ההריון אצל הפרגוד שבו נשמות חקוקין ואומר לה לכי בתי עמי והכנסי במעי אשה פלונית ואומרת האיך אלך במקום הטנופת ואניח מקום טהרה כזה מיד בא מלאך ונוטלת' בעל כרחה ומכניסתה למעי אשה: ועל כרחך אתה נולד. בשעה שהגיע זמן העובר לצאת ממעי אמו ואינו רוצה לצאת משם לפי שהוא צופה מסוף העולם ועד סופו כמו שנא' בהלו נרו עלי ראשי מיד מוציאין אותו בעל כרחו משם: ועל כרחך אתה חי. לפי שיש אדם שהוא מדוכא ביסורין ובשעה שהוא ישן בלילה ואין הנשמה רוצה לחזור מפני עול הצרות שהוא סובל אומר לה הקדוש ברוך הוא חס ושלום לא אכפור באמונתי לעולם אלא אשלם לו הפקדון שהפקיד אצלי וכן הוא אומר בידך אפקיד רוחי ועל כן רגילין לומר אמת ואמונה בלילות. ועל כרחך אתה מת וכו' וכן אתה עתיד ליתן דין וחשבון בקבר עד כאן:
Against your will you are formed The angel in charge of pregnancy comes to the curtain, surrounding the place where the souls are hidden, and says to the neshamah, "Go, my daughter, and enter the inside of such and such a woman." And she says, "How can I go to such a filthy place and leave such a pure place?" Immediately an angel forcefully brings it inside the woman: Against your will you are born When the time has come for the child to emerge from its mother's womb and it does not want to leave, as it watches from one end of the world to the other end, as the saying goes, “When His lamp shined above my head, and by His light I walked through darkness” (Job 29:3) they immediately forcefully remove it from there: Against your will you are living Since there is a person who is oppressed by suffering and while he is sleeping at night and his soul does not want to return from the burden of his troubles, the Holy One, blessed be He, says to it, "I will never deny my faith, but I will repay him the deposit he deposited with me." And so the soul says, "In your hands I entrust my spirit..." (Psalms 31:6) Therefore, we are accustomed to saying "truth and faith" (before Shema) in the evening prayer. And against you will you die, etc. And so you will have to give an account in the grave up to this point:

After a child is formed he gives suffering of pregnancy to the mother. A soul living inside her is fully aware of the mother's pain and suffers with her. After a child is born it cries (suffers) from the loss of the Torah learned during pregnancy, experiences the pain of growing, from pain of getting able to digest food to pain of adjusting to society, teachers, etc. The suffering in life is common for many people. Many people die before their time because of various reasons (sins, improper lifestyle, bad eating habbits, etc.)

The second answer is midrash Bereshis Rabba 65:9

יִצְחָק תָּבַע יִסּוּרִין, אָמַר לְפָנָיו רִבּוֹן כָּל הָעוֹלָמִים אָדָם מֵת בְּלֹא יִסּוּרִים מִדַּת הַדִּין מְתוּחָה כְּנֶגְדּוֹ, מִתּוֹךְ שֶׁאַתָּה מֵבִיא עָלָיו יִסּוּרִים אֵין מִדַּת הַדִּין מְתוּחָה כְּנֶגְדּוֹ. אָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא חַיֶּיךָ דָּבָר טוֹב תָּבַעְתָּ וּמִמְּךָ אֲנִי מַתְחִיל, מִתְּחִלַּת הַסֵּפֶר וְעַד כָּאן אֵין כְּתִיב יִסּוּרִין וְכֵיוָן שֶׁעָמַד יִצְחָק נָתַן לוֹ יִסּוּרִים, וַיְהִי כִּי זָקֵן יִצְחָק וַתִּכְהֶיןָ.
(Rabbi Yehuda bar Simon said) Isaac demanded suffering. He said before Him: ‘Master of the universe, a person dies without suffering, the attribute of justice is outstretched against him. When you bring suffering upon him, the attribute of justice is not outstretched against him.’ The Holy One blessed be He said to him: ‘As you live, you have demanded a good thing, and I will begin with you.’ From the beginning of the book until here, suffering is not written. When Isaac stood, He granted him suffering – “it was when Isaac was old, and [his eyes] dimmed.”


Can you be more explicit?  Yes, against my will I was formed, I was born, I am living, I will die, and I will have to account.  Where is the suffering?

@MauriceMizrahi there are many little things which are yissurim.

That's what I said in a comment to the OP.  But that's weak compared to slavery and war.  You can't put those on the same plane as "little things", however "many" those are.

@MauriceMizrahi it is all weighted in accordance with badness of generation according to the second answer. Certain big evils cause slavery and war, and certain great merits remove many issurim.
